# VBA Paste Values and skip worksheets during loop

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I nearly have what I want but can't seem to get all the way there. I'm trying to grab data from hundreds of worksheets. I want to copy/paste the values of every sheet starting at A5 and going to AG (the rows are varying). One problem I had before was the A column doesn't always have a value even though the rest of the row does. Column A isn't vital to my data collection, therefore I started the copy/paste at B5.

This copied everything that I wanted copied but a few rows on each sheet are formulas and I need the value pasted. This is where I am really lost.

Lastly, there are two sheets "Advanced" and "Pivot" that I don't want on my "Total" sheet.

Here is what I've been using:

```
    Sub CombineData()
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sht.Name <> "Total" And Sht.Range("B5").Value <> "" Then
    Sht.Activate
    LastRow = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("B5", Cells(LastRow, "AG")).Copy
    Sheets("Total").Select
    Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Else
    End If
    Next Sht


    End Sub
```

Any help would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub CombineData()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsTot As Worksheet
    Dim aData As Variant

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsTot = wb.Sheets("Total")

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If InStr(1, " " & wsTot.Name & " Advanced Pivot ", " " & ws.Name & " ", vbTextCompare) = 0 _
        And Len(Trim(ws.Range("B5").Value)) > 0 Then
            aData = ws.Range("B5:AG" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row).Value
            wsTot.Cells(wsTot.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(UBound(aData, 1), UBound(aData, 2)).Value = aData
            Erase aData
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought my head was going to explode from banging it against the wall.